# Why is Control-C not killing my bash script? And how to kill a bash script just with keyboard controls and without kill/killall?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is the content of test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e
echo start
meld file1 file2
echo finished
```

Here is all fine. The GUI-Program meld opens. I close meld via GUI. All fine.

`bash test.sh`

output:

```
start
end
```

Now the same script but I do not close meld via GUI. I go back to the Terminal and press Control-C. You see the ^C in the terminal and meld is closing/killed. But the script is running further. And is executing the `echo finished`

`bash test.sh`

output:

```
start
^Cfinished
```

Do anyone has a clue why Control-C not killing the script?

Comment: Many GUI programs _deliberately_ detach them from whatever process invoked them; this lets you close a terminal without closing all other programs you started from that terminal and is otherwise typically considered (from the perspective of that GUI tool's end-users) to be a Good Thing.

Comment: Beyond that, we'd need to know why you think the script isn't exiting. It's very plausible that the script **has** exited, but your terminal is held open by `meld` keeping a handle on it, should `meld` _not_ be self-daemonizing properly. But this is something we can't really test without installing `meld` ourselves, unless you give enough information in the question itself to allow an accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Have you looked in `ps` to see if `bash test.sh` is still there?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your script like this:

```
echo 'start'
meld
sleep 5
echo 'finished'
```

you can break your script with two CTRL + C command. why?

Your first CTRL + C command will break meld GUI and your second one will break your bash script and you won't see last echo command.

The reason you always see finished is: meld is run successfully and bash script will run other lines continuously.
you just can't see output because out stream is controlled by meld and you just see output when you break meld GUI with CTRL + C.
you can check more on [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/1653229/when-pressed-ctrlc-only-break-out-of-current-function-and-not-whole-bash-script).